# How to make my image map responsive using javascript

Tags: javascript, responsive, imagemap

I am beginner to web development and am trying to make an image map responsive. It is a map that I have made on illustrator and have created an svg image with coordinates. I have tried a few different variations of jquery bu none of them seem to successfully make the map responsive so i can click on the different sections at any size.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <img id="img_ID" src="bar-crawl-map.svg" usemap="#image-map" border="0" width="100%" alt="Map of popular bar areas in Manchester">
</div>

Map
<map id="map_ID" name="image-map">
  <area name="dansgate" shape="poly" coords="449.8,211.27 449.8,180.18 500.46,203.21 490.5,259.91 468.22,320.65 442.89,401.24 
  415.26,488.75 384.17,577.4 326.6,550.92 346.18,496.81 369.2,431.18 401.44,344.83 434.83,255.02            "href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/deansgate" alt="Deansgate">

  <area name="castlefield" shape="poly" coords="92.88,544.01 106.69,504.87 141.23,459.96 242.55,492.2 303.58,519.83 319.69,533.65 
  315.09,577.4 309.33,628.06 206.28,672.97 143.54,624.61            " href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/castlefield" alt="Castlefield">

  <area name="spinningfields" shape="poly" coords="205.71,370.16 373.81,418.84 419.05,297.45 449.8,211.27 406.05,195.15 270.19,276.9"            href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinningfields" alt="Spinningfields">

  <area name="nq" shape="poly" coords="593.62,95.26 518.78,147.07 508.42,205.79 489.5,259.91 509.57,287.54 527.99,273.72 
  616.65,319.78 647.73,362.38 654.64,362.38 691.48,350.87 746.75,338.2 781.29,318.63 797.41,303.66"             href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/northern-quarter" alt="Northern Quarter">
</map>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ImageMap = function(map, img) {
      var n,
        areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
        len = areas.length,
        coords = [],
        previousWidth = 128;
      for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
      }
      this.resize = function() {
        var n, m, clen,
          x = img.offsetWidth / previousWidth;
        for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
          clen = coords[n].length;
          for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
            coords[n][m] *= x;
          }
          areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
        }
        previousWidth = img.offsetWidth;
        return true;
      };
      window.onresize = this.resize;
    },
    imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('map_ID'), document.getElementById('img_ID'));
  imageMap.resize();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you share at least something working? With current code shared seems not enough to solve your question. Thanks

Comment: When you take a look at the SVG file, you'll see that it doesn't look too different from HTML. Guess what, pretty much every current Browser agrees with you. You can put your SVG right inside the HTML-markup and the browser can deal with it. So now, that you have paths and shapes in your markup, what do you need that image-map for? You can add event listeners right onto the shapes.

Comment: thanks @GeorgeWang yes sorry it wouldn't let me upload what I had in the javascript. I have now added more detail

Comment: thanks @Thomas i have just added the svg into the html document but the problem is I dont understand what javascript to add to make it responsive.